# method UItextfield - after I type in a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm looking for a method of UITextField, which makes a thing after I type in a UITextField.

I have a method to conduct a calculation I use a button, but I do not want to use, I want you to run this method after I type numbers in UITextField.

any tips for which method to use?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Implement the `UITextFieldFieldDelegate` protocol
2. Set the delegate of your textfields to your view controller

`self.textField.delegate = self;`

Then Implement the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self doCalculations];
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Kevin,

This method you spent more or less worked.

When I type a value in the calculation is TextField with a backwardness of one character.

TextField = 11

Return Label: 111

Answer (score 1):

You can use `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` to get the typed text straight away. Or you can use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` to capture when the user hits return and just read the text out of the text field at that time. Both of these methods are in the UITextFieldDelegate protocol, the docs for which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).

EDIT:

Alternatively you could use `[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];` and implement the textChanged method to capture the EditingChanged event.

Comment: Thanks for adding the Edit tag. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your ViewContoller.h
//Implement UITextFieldFieldDelegate protocol


//In your ViewContoller.m
//where you are creating your textfield.
textField.delegate = self;

// There are 2 delegate method that you can implement
// this method will be called whwn ever you enter a a letter.
// say you enter 'abcd' then this method will be called 4 times.  
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
//do your calculation if required
    return YES;
}

//this method will be called when the textField will end editing, i.e when the keyboard resigns of the control goes to some other textField/textView
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

}
```

Based on your requirement, you can either do your calculation in the 1st or the 2nd method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so by using this code :-

This code Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        [self yourMethodName];  //The method which you want to call.
        return YES;
    }
```

and call the UITextFieldField Delegate.For better understanding of this you can refer this:-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Hope this will help you out.